# Access framebuffer /dev/fb0 in AWS EC2 (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: server, amazon-ec2, framebuffer, fbgrab

My ultimate goal is to use `fbgrab` program on EC2. Whenever I try `fbgrab -c 1 screenshot.png`, I get:

> Could not open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory

How can I install/enable it in my Ubuntu Server? It is hosted on AWS EC2 with current version 14.04.

As I said, my ultimate goal is to use fbgrab, so if there is any workaround that bypass FrameBuffer, I'm open to it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research earlier. The problem are `linux-image-aws` and `linux-image-extra-aws` packages. They don't have framebuffer driver in them.

Solution is to use `linux-image-gke` packages. Although you will lose AWS optimization (I heard it also makes your server a bit slow), but you will get framebuffer device.

To install them run `apt install linux-image-4.4.0-1031-gke linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1031-gke`.

Note: If you have both `linux-image-4.4.0-1049-aws` and `linux-image-4.4.0-1031-gke` installed, Linux will prefer `linux-image-4.4.0-1049-aws` because of higher version number. Make sure you purge those AWS packages after you installed GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) packages.

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04:**

Things have changed a bit in Ubuntu 18.04. This will do the job now :)

```
sudo apt purge -y linux-image-aws linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install -y linux-image-gcp
sudo apt install -y linux-modules-extra-$(ls /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-*-gcp | grep -oP 'vmlinuz-\K.*'-gcp)
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-gcp linux-image-$(ls /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-*-gcp | grep -oP 'vmlinuz-\K.*'-gcp) linux-modules-extra-$(ls /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-*-gcp | grep -oP 'vmlinuz-\K.*'-gcp)
sudo reboot
```